# cascade persist results in null column value for a ManyToMany entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Owner:

```
@Entity
public class Strategy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "StrategyHost", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "strategyId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "hostId")})
    private Set<Host> hostName;

}
```

Related entity:

```
@Entity
public class Host {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "hostName")
    private List<Strategy> strategies;

    public Host(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void testStrategyWithHosts() {
    Strategy s = new Strategy();

    Set<Host> hosts= new HashSet<>();
    hosts.add(Host.builder().name("aaa").build());
    hosts.add(Host.builder().name("bbb").build());
    s.setHostName(hosts);
    Strategy saved= strategyDao.save(s);
    Set<Host> hostName = saved.getHostName();
}
```

debug shows the persisted `saved` object having Host:

[image: result for cascade type persist only]

Where are `name` values? However, if I add `merge` in cascade type array, `name` are valued. Why insert (not update managed entities) operation for related entities must have merge cascade type? Although log shows nothing suspicious:

> insert into strategy... 
>   insert into host... 
>   insert into host... 
>   update strategy ... 
>   insert into strategy_host ... 
>   insert into strategy_host ...

Comment: Are you using Lombok? If yes then remove lombot annotations for getter ans setter and add getters and setters explicitly and try

Comment: @pvpkiran they are also null in db.

Comment: @pvpkiran but they are not if also using cascade type merge.

Comment: `CascadeType` is ` javax.persistence.CascadeType` ?

Comment: @pvpkiran yes it is.